# Bug in products export - Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, products, export

I have a problem with exporting all products in magento 1.9.2.1.

I want to export sku, name, price and manufacturer. It's okay but i have several lines for an unique sku.

The first line shows the correct name, the correct price and the correct manufacturer and the second line shows only the sku.

I guess it's because of the images.

If i have 3 images for a product, i have the correct line + two blank lines
If i have 5 images for a product, i have the correct line + four blaank lines.

Do you have an idea why ? We need a good file in order to re-import it.

Thanks

EDIT

9084709010(sku)    GoodName  GoodPrice  Good manufacturer 
9084709010
9084709010
9084709010
9084709010

And the number of blank lines with only sku is the same as the number of pictures

Answer (score 0):

The blank lines should reflect if there's multiple values. In my memory, that was different before but should not be a problem.

Use the AutoFilter option in excel an filter a value what has every product on one line only. If you set the filter to "not empty" it should give you a csv with only the important lines. Copy & Paste that into a new file, modifiy data and upload again.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am already using System > Import / Export > Dataflow :/ Do you know a free module ?

Comment: no. Everybod'y working with the Dataflow since it's working like a charm usually. Also I do not get exactly what is in the different lines. Maybe drop a source example of the csv?

Comment: Ok for the example i'm going to edit my post

Comment: I edited the answer too. Seems to be a new standard behaviout (before it was comma seperated within the field)

Answer (score 0):

Please override this core file

```
--- app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php    2017-06-13 22:19:38.344626989 +0000
+++ app/code/local/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php   2017-06-13 22:18:26.416411730 +0000
@@ -213,8 +213,16 @@
             $batchExport->load($batchExportId);
             $row = $batchExport->getBatchData();

+            // @MFIXME Skip rows with empty values
+            $is_empty = true;
             foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
                 $csvData[] = isset($row[$field]) ? $row[$field] : '';
+                if ( $is_empty && ! empty( $row[$field] ) ) {
+                    $is_empty = false;
+                }
+            }
+            if ( $is_empty ) {
+                continue;
             }
             $csvData = $this->getCsvString($csvData);
             $io->write($csvData);
```